# (Android) CAT S40 yellow button

Tags: android, button

I am using CAT S40, and I would like to use yellow (hardware) button in my application (override it). Does anyone know how to do that?How do I find keycode for that button?

Comment: Override `onKeyDown()` in your activity and log the output. Run the app and press the button. See what comes out in the logs.

Comment: Thanks. I found out that keyCode is 27. Is there any way I could call some activity when pressing this button?

Comment: You are very lucky. That maps to `KEYCODE_CAMERA`, and there is [a broadcast `Intent` action (`ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON`) associated with that](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON). Try putting a `<receiver>` in your manifest for that `Intent` action, and see if you get control. Note that it might trigger some other built-in app first, so you might need to play with your `<intent-filter>` priority to try to get control.

Comment: Can I use it with one single activity in my project?

Comment: Um, you can have as many activities as you want. If you are trying to *start* some activity (my interpretation of "call some activity"), that will have to be done via a `BroadcastReceiver`, registered in the manifest. The receiver will have to call `startActivity()`. At least, that is how it works with the CAMERA button on other Android devices. If you need more assistance specifically with this device, contact its manufacturer.

Comment: Yeah, but if I register it in manifest, it can be always triggered. I want it to be triggered only when specific activity si foreground. Sorry for bad explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can override **OnKeyDown** (/OnKeyUp) on your main activity, in order to find keycode and handle button click :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
//put a breakpoint here and/or implement button action
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```